# best way to append info using tags and in a (txt) .dat file. From a form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a data file that is called customer.dat... From a user input box I want to update this file...
Except I'm not using csv, this is what I'm using?
Here is my data file...

```
<emulator>
<hostname>wfbscd13   </hostname>
<domain>cadence.com   </domain>
<nameserver>158.140,161.4 </nameserver>
<ipaddr>158.140.161.55 </ipaddr>
<netmask>255.255.255.0 </netmask>
<gateway>158.140.161.254 </gateway>
<ntpserver>ntp-katrine.cadence.com </ntpserver>
<tz>America/New_York </tz>
</emulator>
```

My question is what the best way to replace the information between the tags? And if it's not a big deal, a small example... Appreciate it, thanks...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is XML parser like DOM or SimpleXML. Here I give you a piece of code how to get information from your file, and how to change values. Read up on [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php) in PHP manual for more information:

```
$sxml = new SimpleXMLElement('<emulator>
<hostname>wfbscd13   </hostname>
<domain>cadence.com   </domain>
<nameserver>158.140,161.4 </nameserver>
<ipaddr>158.140.161.55 </ipaddr>
<netmask>255.255.255.0 </netmask>
<gateway>158.140.161.254 </gateway>
<ntpserver>ntp-katrine.cadence.com </ntpserver>
<tz>America/New_York </tz>
</emulator>');

//or you can load an XML file into a SimpleXML object:
$myXML = simplexml_load_file('myfile.xml');
//you can now call $myXML->tz to get tz node's value;

//change hostname node
$sxml->hostname='aa';

//get <tz> node's value
$myvalue = $sxml->tz;

//outputs changed xml structure, save it in a variable and do what u need
echo $sxml->saveXML();
```